# Texto da medalha "Ressurgimento"

Tags: bug, internacionalização, medalhas

[image: print da descrição]

O texto da medalha diz que a resposta deve ter "mais de 2 pontos", no entanto eu a ganhei quando minha resposta alcançou exatamente 2 pontos. Assim sendo, acredito que o texto da medalha deveria ser "com **pelo menos** 2 pontos".

Texto original no SO-en:

> Answer more than 30 days after a question was asked as first answer scoring **2 or more**

É um detalhe que não atrapalha em nada, mas resolvi deixar registrado aqui no meta.

Comment: Novamente me deparei com esse bug. 